# LINQ : Applying a filter in where clause but need to inspect the value of a SUM (subquery) - explained inside

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, sum, where-clause, dynamic-sql

I have the following linq and its working great but i need to be able to check a variable and depending on value only show a subset of the records. I will explain..

Here is the SQL

```
var test = from c in db.C
 select new {
  Period = c.M.Period,
  Group = c.Code,
  Code = c.ClientCode,
  Name = c.ClientName,
  Amount = (System.Int32)
   ((from m0 in db.M
     where
      m0.ClientCode == c.ClientCode
       group m0 by new {
        m0.ClientCode
         } into g
          select new {
           Expr1 = (System.Int32)g.Sum(p => p.Amount)
    }).First().Expr1)
 }
```

This returns 6 records, The amount is the following in each record

100
200
300
400
500
600

I need to dynamically bolt on a where and check a variable called filter (in c#) and if filter is = 1 then return all records <300  and if filter is = 2 return all records >= 300 and if the variable is empty don't apply any filter and return all records.

Now where i am getting confused is that Amount isn't in the DB it is actually subquery.

Can anyone lend a hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would help if you simplified your query to start with. You're using anonymous types for no particular reason (if there's only a single property, why bother?) and grouping by a value which you've already filtered by. In other words, your query is equivalent to:

```
var test = from c in db.C
 select new {
  Period = c.M.Period,
  Group = c.Code,
  Code = c.ClientCode,
  Name = c.ClientName,
  Amount = db.M
             .Where(m0 => m0.ClientCode == c.ClientCode)
             .Sum(m0 => m0.Amount)
};
```

Having a simpler query may make it easier to fix the rest of your problem. It may be as simple as:

```
var filtered = filter == 1 ? test.Where(t => t.Amount < 300)
             : filter == 2 ? test.Where(t => t.Amount >= 300)
             : test;
```

Comment: Nice Jon! Whats the difference using - whats it called query syntax and Lambdas??  i.e. I like what you did above and i managed to covert it to a standard syntax (is that the correct name) Amount1 = (from m1 in m where m1.ClientCode == c.ClientCode
select m1.Amount).Sum()

Comment: I suppose the where we have to leave as a lambda expression? I am little confused about the difference between the 2 .. I need to do some investigating i think.... What are the 2 names of the different syntax?

Comment: Well, the "from ... where ... select" is a *query expression*. There's no standard name for using extension methods directly - some call it "dot notation".

Comment: Great jon! thank you ....  Is there a perference to either??   Actually correct me if i am wrong but i managed to put your example (sub select) into query expression - But the where - i would love to know if its possible ?? I don't see it being posslbe in query expression but i am forced to use the Where extension method - or am i wrong?  Wow I am learning a lot here

Comment: @Martin: I'm not sure I understand your question - the "where" is already in a query expression in your modified example. You should be familiar with both forms so you can use the most readable approach for any particular situation.

Comment: Hi jOn, no its tagged on the end as per your example like lambda..  hence i have  Amount1 = (from m1 in m where m1.ClientCode == c.ClientCode select m1.Amount).Sum()  and then i this  var filtered = filter == 1 ? results.Where(t => t.Amount1 < 101)
    : filter == 2 ? results.Where(t => t.Amount1 >= 200)
    : results;

Comment: @Martin: Oh, I see... you *could* use a "from ... where ... select" query expression there (for each case) but it would look really ugly.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var test = from c in db.C
select new {

    Period = c.M.Period,
    Group = c.Code,
    Code = c.ClientCode,
    Name = c.ClientName,
    Amount = (System.Int32)
        ((from m0 in db.M
            where
            m0.ClientCode == c.ClientCode
            group m0 by new {
            m0.ClientCode
                } into g
                select new {
                Expr1 = (System.Int32)g.Sum(p => p.Amount)
                }).First().Expr1).Where(i => 
                    {
                        if (filter == 1) 
                            i.Expr1 < 300; 
                            else if (filter == 2) 
                            i.Expr1 >= 300; 
                    })
```

Comment: Thanks Dean. Its true what jon said .. i was using an anonymous type for nothing .. i have re edited and now it is  Amount1 = (from m1 in m where m1.ClientCode == c.ClientCode select m1.Amount).Sum()

Answer (score 1):

Basically I took Jon's answer and integrated the filter into the query:

```
int filter = 1;

Func<int, bool> isRelevant = (amount)=>{
    switch(filter)
    {
        case 1: return amount < 300;
        case 2: return amount > 300;
        default: throw new ArgumentException();
    }
};

var test = from c in db.C
            let amount = db.M
                            .Where(m0 => m0.ClientCode == c.ClientCode)
                            .Sum(m0 => m0.Amount)
            where isRelevant(amount)
            select new
            {
                Period = c.M.Period,
                Group = c.Code,
                Code = c.ClientCode,
                Name = c.ClientName,
                Amount = amount
            };
```

Comment: +1 for a great Func ... I like it! I think i will stick with lambda query though... THanks a lot for your help.